# How to solve the Jmeter proxy certificate error

Tags: jmeter

Whenever i try to record the requests, in view result tree in few requests sometime
The below error is coming sometime and sometime not.
"Response message:Software caused connection abort: recv failed
**ensure browser is set to accept the Jmeter proxy certificate error is coming**."

Jmeter proxy certificate is already installed.

I am trying to record the requests and expecting no error in view result tree.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the following message:

> ensure browser is set to accept the Jmeter proxy certificate error is coming

it means that the certificate is NOT installed into the browser you're using for recording. If it's there check its validity, by default JMeter's certificate is valid for 7 days only (configurable by [proxy.cert.validity](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#test_script_recorder_cert) JMeter Property)

If this is the case -

1. Remove the outdated certificate from the browser
2. Remove `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` and `proxyserver.jks` files from "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
3. Restart [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
4. Install the newly generated certificate into your browser
5. It is also a good idea to [clear your browsing history](https://www.howtogeek.com/304218/how-to-clear-your-history-in-any-browser/) before recording

Also be aware of an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates.